# Lock user session and login to another after delay minutes

Tags: linux, bash, auto-login, logout

I have two accounts: `admin` with password and `user` without pass.

When I'm logged on admin, I want to lock `admin` and switch to `user` when idle about 10min.

A lot of tutorials talk about logging in to the console or manual clicking interface. In my problem, I think about the GUI but via script.

What should I be looking for to write a script?

I think you need to detect idle 10 minutes and execute e.g. a bash script that will block `admin` and switch to `user`.

Comment: You need to approach the problem in steps. You need to detect 10 mins of inactivity, log admin out, and sign user in, each on their own, and then put the scripts together. Please show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Resolve for this problem is command `loginctl` and `xidle`:

```
$ loginctl list-sessions
SESSION  UID USER   SEAT  TTY
      2 1020 user   seat0 tty2
      5 1044 admin  seat0 tty3
```

After get session ID we switch to logged accont:

```
$ loginctl activate 2
```

The above command locks the session of the `admin` and immediately switches to the `user` account.

For user idle detection I used `xidle`

```
xidle -timeout 120 -program "/usr/bin/sh /switch_user.sh"
```

switch_user.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
id=$(loginctl list-sessions | grep user | awk -F' ' '{print $1}')
loginctl activate "$id"
```